# How do I sort by Ordering[Option[String]]?

Tags: scala

```scala
val scoreSeq_opition: Seq[Option[String]] = List(Some("ngksf"),Some("fmgfdmg"),Some("mbmd"),None)
val nullOrdering: Ordering[Option[String]] = ????
```

I would like to sort by Ordering[Option[String]] if the above code.
In that case, unlike the standard, we want None to be listed after Some, and Option[String] should be in the normal sort order for String.
Last time we sorted strings in Score, but this time we are simply sorting strings of strings.

Comment: @GaëlJ It is the same question, but that one doesn't have a correct answer, so not sure what the rules are on whether this is a duplicate or not.

Comment: You're right, removed my close vote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `Option[String]` it looks like this:

```
implicit val ord: Ordering[Option[String]] =
   Ordering.by(x => (x.isEmpty, x.getOrElse("")))
```

I am presuming that `Score` is just a type alias for `Option[String]` otherwise you need to create an `Ordering[Score]` with the appropriate rules. In that case the ordering can be in the companion object where the compiler will find it if it needs it.

Comment: println(scoreSeq.sorted(ord)) display like this?

Comment: If implicit is in scope, you don't need to specify it. Otherwise yes.